# css Turn a drop-down menu into a drop-up footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footer

I found a dropdown menu model that I want to reverse, to make it a "dropup" menu, opening from bottom to top.

What I have is this :

HTML

```
<div class="get-started">

  <a href="#" id="get-started-close">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxzdmcgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNHB4IiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNCAxNCIgd2lkdGg9IjE0cHgiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6c2tldGNoPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LmJvaGVtaWFuY29kaW5nLmNvbS9za2V0Y2gvbnMiIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hsaW5rIj48dGl0bGUvPjxkZXNjLz48ZGVmcy8+PGcgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgZmlsbC1ydWxlPSJldmVub2RkIiBpZD0iUGFnZS0xIiBzdHJva2U9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMSI+PGcgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgaWQ9IkNvcmUiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKC0zNDEuMDAwMDAwLCAtODkuMDAwMDAwKSI+PGcgaWQ9ImNsb3NlIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSgzNDEuMDAwMDAwLCA4OS4wMDAwMDApIj48cGF0aCBkPSJNMTQsMS40IEwxMi42LDAgTDcsNS42IEwxLjQsMCBMMCwxLjQgTDUuNiw3IEwwLDEyLjYgTDEuNCwxNCBMNyw4LjQgTDEyLjYsMTQgTDE0LDEyLjYgTDguNCw3IEwxNCwxLjQgWiIgaWQ9IlNoYXBlIi8+PC9nPjwvZz48L2c+PC9zdmc+" height="18" width="18">
  </a>

  <div class="get-started-container">
    <div class="row no-margin">

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading first">Button 1</h2>
        <div class="line margin-bottom-md"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading">Button 2</h2>
        <div class="line margin-bottom-md"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading">Button 3</h2>
        <div class="line margin-bottom-md"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading">Button 4</h2>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<nav>
  <a href="#" class="no-padding-right get-stated-show" id="get-started-btn">CLICK HERE</a>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.get-started {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 101);
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  display: none;
}

#get-started-btn {
  font: 100 14px/20px 'Open Sans', Verdana, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 101);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 19px;
  padding: 11px 20px 11px 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}

#get-started-btn:hover,
#get-started-btn:active {
  text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 25px 4px rgba(255, 0, 101, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: -3px 0px 25px 4px rgba(255, 0, 101, 0.4);
  box-shadow: -3px 0px 25px 4px rgba(255, 0, 101, 0.4);
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#get-started-btn:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#get-started-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#get-started-close:hover,
#get-started-close:active,
#get-started-close:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

.get-started-container {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.get-started-heading {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  background: rgb(255, 127, 177);
  margin: auto auto 15px auto;

}

.white-link-sm {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.white-link-sm:hover,
.white-link-sm:active,
.white-link-sm:focus {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.get-stated-hide {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .get-started-heading.first {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .get-started-heading {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#get-started-btn, #get-started-close').click(function () {
          $('.get-started').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

This is to me very complex and I don't know what to modify in the CSS to have it reversed. Any tips on how to achieve it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Change `top: 19px;` to `bottom: 19px;`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer but it simply moves the button to open the menu at the bottom of the page. The menu is still opening from top to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the position of div "get-started" is from relative to absolute and bottom with 0. 
If you give "top:0px" in div "get-started", the drop-down menu will open from top to bottom.

Here is the code:

```css
body{background:#000;}
.get-started {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 101);
  color: #fff;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  display: none;
}

#get-started-btn {
  font: 100 14px/20px 'Open Sans', Verdana, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 101);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 19px;
  padding: 11px 20px 11px 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border:#FFF 2px solid;
}

#get-started-btn:hover,
#get-started-btn:active {
  text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 25px 4px rgba(255, 0, 101, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: -3px 0px 25px 4px rgba(255, 0, 101, 0.4);
  box-shadow: -3px 0px 25px 4px rgba(255, 0, 101, 0.4);
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#get-started-btn:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#get-started-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#get-started-close:hover,
#get-started-close:active,
#get-started-close:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

.get-started-container {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.get-started-heading {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  background: rgb(255, 127, 177);
  margin: auto auto 15px auto;

}

.white-link-sm {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.white-link-sm:hover,
.white-link-sm:active,
.white-link-sm:focus {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.get-stated-hide {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .get-started-heading.first {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .get-started-heading {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="get-started">

  <a href="#" id="get-started-close">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" height="18" width="18">
  </a>

  <div class="get-started-container">
    <div class="row no-margin">

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading first">Button 1</h2>
        <div class="line margin-bottom-md"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading">Button 2</h2>
        <div class="line margin-bottom-md"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading">Button 3</h2>
        <div class="line margin-bottom-md"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading">Button 4</h2>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="no-padding-right get-stated-show" id="get-started-btn">CLICK HERE</a>
</nav>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#get-started-btn, #get-started-close').click(function () {
          $('.get-started').slideToggle();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! However, the drop-up menu is going all the way to the top of the page. I'd like to have it "contained" in a div at the bottom of the page. How would that work ?

Comment: change the height of div "get-started" to "height:auto"

Comment: Thanks. One more thing: when I change "get-started" from relative to absolute and bottom with 0, the nav buttom does not get "pushed" anymore by the drop-up menu. It just stays where it is and I would like it to move up, at the same time as the drop-up menu.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will move up the nav button at the same time as the drop-up menu.

Have to change the js code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#get-started-btn, #get-started-close').click(function () {
          $('.get-started').toggle();
          var ht= $('.get-started').height();
          if($('.get-started').is(":visible")){         
            $("#get-started-btn").animate({bottom:ht+19+'px'});
          }
          else{
              $("#get-started-btn").animate({bottom:19+'px'});
          }
    });



});
```

```css
body{background:#000;}
.get-started {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 101);
  color: #fff;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  display: none;
}

#get-started-btn {
  font: 100 14px/20px 'Open Sans', Verdana, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(255, 0, 101);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 19px;
  padding: 11px 20px 11px 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border:#FFF 2px solid;
}

#get-started-btn:hover,
#get-started-btn:active {
  text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0px 25px 4px rgba(255, 0, 101, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: -3px 0px 25px 4px rgba(255, 0, 101, 0.4);
  box-shadow: -3px 0px 25px 4px rgba(255, 0, 101, 0.4);
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:box-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#get-started-btn:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#get-started-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#get-started-close:hover,
#get-started-close:active,
#get-started-close:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}

.get-started-container {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.get-started-heading {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
  background: rgb(255, 127, 177);
  margin: auto auto 15px auto;

}

.white-link-sm {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.white-link-sm:hover,
.white-link-sm:active,
.white-link-sm:focus {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.get-stated-hide {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .get-started-heading.first {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .get-started-heading {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="get-started">

  <a href="#" id="get-started-close">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" height="18" width="18">
  </a>

  <div class="get-started-container">
    <div class="row no-margin">

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading first">Button 1</h2>
        <div class="line margin-bottom-md"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading">Button 2</h2>
        <div class="line margin-bottom-md"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading">Button 3</h2>
        <div class="line margin-bottom-md"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="get-started-heading">Button 4</h2>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 1
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 2
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="white-link-sm">
                Content 3
              </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<nav>
  <a href="#" class="no-padding-right get-stated-show" id="get-started-btn">CLICK HERE</a>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#get-started-btn, #get-started-close').click(function () {
          $('.get-started').toggle();
    var ht= $('.get-started').height();
    if($('.get-started').is(":visible")){     
   $("#get-started-btn").animate({bottom:ht+19+'px'});
    }
    else{
     $("#get-started-btn").animate({bottom:19+'px'});
    }
    });
 
 
 
});


</script>
```

Comment: Hi P. Das, thank you, we are getting there. Although now, the drop-up menu displays without any progression.